# Confidence interval for a normal mean when the variance is unknown

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

For [this problem](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3XEB3ZWO9IMRFhFR1JOMEYycjQ/edit?pli=1) , how to calculate when $t.025,8 = 2.306$?

Comment: just realize the value can be find from a so-called T-distribution table

Answer (score 1):

Just look up the [t distribution table](http://www.math.unb.ca/~knight/utility/t-table.htm).